# Why is my codesigned app still quarantined by macOS?

Tags: applescript, code-signing, gatekeeper

I have a .app that is quarantined. But I am super confused - how can my .app be properly codesigned and yet still be quarantined by Apple? I have an app called iTest.app that I downloaded from my server and made sure that it was codesigned correctly but yet it is still quarantined? I thought that having a valid code signature was the whole point of getting past Gatekeeper?

```
MyMac-7:Downloads user$ ls -l@ iTest.app
total 0
drwxr-xr-x@ 7 user staff  238 Apr 21 08:05 Contents
com.apple.quarantine     67 

MyiMac-7:Downloads user$ codesign --verify --deep --strict -vvvvvvv 
iTest.app
iTest.app: valid on disk
iTest.app: satisfies its Designated Requirement

MyiMac-7:Downloads user$ spctl -a -t exec -vvvvvvv iTest.app
iTest.app: accepted
source=Developer ID
origin=Developer ID Application: myID
```

Answer (score 2):

The `com.apple.quarantine` is an OS X feature, this happens every time you download from the internet : 
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/Carbon/RN-LaunchServices/index.html

Comment: is there any work around for this?  It keeps placing my download in some random /private/var path which screws up my Applescript code.